# Why can't I assign to var in Scala subclass?

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor

Suppose I have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class A (var is_happy : Boolean) {
  def toggle_happiness();
}
```

And now I want to define a concrete class which implements the `toggle_happiness()` method:

```
class B (is_happy : Boolean) extends A (is_happy) {
  def toggle_happiness() = {
    is_happy = !is_happy
  }
}
```

Scala's compiler gives me:

```
error: reassignment to val
   is_happy = !is_happy
            ^
```

What's going on here?  I thought that `is_happy` referred to a `var` in my class that is set by my constructor.  Do I have a conflict with the name `is_happy`?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515931/idiomatic-scala-way-to-deal-with-base-vs-derived-class-field-names).  Essentially, Scala thinks that you're trying to assign to the constructor parameter, `is_happy`, rather than the `var`, `is_happy`, which just happens to have the same name.  Some solutions are to:

- *Make the `var` abstract* in the base class.
- *Rename the constructor parameter* (e.g. `_is_happy`). Since parameter names are part of the public API of your constructors/methods, this may not be advisable.

You're fortunate that the problem was detected at compile time in your case.  This issue can lead to [very surprising runtime behavior when it goes undetected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657248/differences-when-overriding-inherited-constructor-fields).

Comment: that or rename the constructor parameter so that you have something like `class B(_is_happy: Boolean) extends A(_is_happy)`

Comment: @Geoff That works, but parameter names are part of the API (due to named parameters), so it may not be the best option.

Comment: It feels like someone gets bitten by this behavior every week :/

Comment: @kassens Yeah, I think it's safe to say that it's a pretty [common mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332574/common-programming-mistakes-for-scala-developers-to-avoid/6657547#6657547).  I wasn't even aware of it until [Gregor Scheidt pointed it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515931/idiomatic-scala-way-to-deal-with-base-vs-derived-class-field-names), and I've been using Scala for a couple years now!

Comment: Are you sure about the possibility to "Override the var in the derived class"? As far as I can tell one cannot override a var! So This advice is valid for a `val`, but not fors a `var`.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I can only hope that my statement was correct when I made it, but it's certainly incorrect in Scala 2.10. *Abstract* vars, on the other hand, can be overridden.

Comment: I've gone back to scala 2.8.0 (released one solid year before your answer) and can confirm that it does not work in this version either. Maybe your should remove  point (3) from your answer (or better merge point (1) and (3), as in "Make the var abstract in the base class and override it in the derived class"

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I decided to just take it out, since it's unnecessary to override an abstract field. Thanks for catching the error!

Comment: How do you "make the var abstract"? If I try `class Baz(abstract var Blah: Int) {}` I get:  `abstract' modifier can be used only for classes; it should be omitted for abstract members
class Baz(abstract var Blah: Int) {}

Comment: @bbarker Like this: `abstract class A { var is_happy: Boolean }`

Answer (score 1):

There is another simple solution. One that only requires to modify `B` (no need to change the base class) and won't modify the interface (no parameter renaming).
Just introduce a private method that returns this, and explicitly dereference this:

```
class B (var is_happy : Boolean) extends A {
  private def self = this
  def toggle_happiness() = {
    self.is_happy = !self.is_happy
  }
}
```

Note that this work around is localized to `B`. Everywhere else (included in derived classes) you can keep using just `is_happy` (no need for `self.is_happy`).

---

As a side note, we should really be able to directly dereference `this`, as in `this.is_happy` (instead of adding the `self` method and doing `self.is_happy`). But for some reason the compiler will blindly treat `this.is_happy` the same as `is_happy`, so we get back to square one and `this.is_happy` actually still point to `B`'s parameter rather than `A`'s variable. This very much looks like a compiler bug to me.