# Differences when overriding inherited constructor fields?

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor, language-design, field

Consider this simple Scala class:

```
class A(val d: Int)
```

Is there a difference in Scala (either in behaviour or generated bytecode) between

```
class B(d: Int) extends A(d)
```

and

```
class B(override val d: Int) extends A(d)
```

or are both equivalent? If they are different, what would be the specific usecase for each of them?

Would it be different if `A` was defined as `class A(var d: Int)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For vals, there is no semantic difference.  However, *there may be a difference in the generated bytecode*.  In particular, if a method defined in the derived class refers to `d`, it refers to the constructor parameter `d` rather than to the `val` of the same name.  This is implemented via an additional private field generated for the derived class.

For vars, there *is* a **difference in behavior**.  Without an override, any methods that refer to `d` from within the derived class will be referring to the constructor parameter, while callers referencing `d` from outside the class will get the field.  In this case, the two values may differ (if the value has changed since construction).

Here's a session that demonstrates the behavior with a var:

```
scala> class A(var d: Int)
defined class A

scala> class B(d: Int) extends A(d) { override def toString = "d: " + d }
defined class B

scala> val b = new B(1)
b: B = d: 1

scala> b.d = 2

scala> b.d
res1: Int = 2

scala> b
res2: B = d: 1
```

This question is related: [Idiomatic Scala way to deal with base vs derived class field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515931/idiomatic-scala-way-to-deal-with-base-vs-derived-class-field-names).